# How secure is JSF2.0/primefaces ? (Do I really need spring security to make secure apps)

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces, ejb

English is not my first language. Sorry for any mistakes upfront.

Here is my project structure:

- An EJB project for handling the mapping and persistence...
- A java web project that uses JSF and primeFaces with the managed beans

In my java web project all my managed bean are @Sessionscoped to make sure that only authenticated users can browse between the different xhtml view pages. is this secure enough to make sure that only logged users can have access to specific pages or I should add another layer of security to my web app ?

Comment: you need to use filters and interceptor in order to achieve this

Comment: @shreyanshjogi I have never created a "secure" java ee application. Can you point me to what I should look for specifically ? in other words what should I type in google to look for some good answers "how to create java filters ?"

Comment: Expecting that the @Sessionscoped annotation says anything about security is a very risky assumption. Although it may work for your set up, the "scope of a session" has nothing to do with security, and even non-authenticated users can have a session.

Comment: @Matt hmm, "non authentificated users can have a session" makes perfect sens , haven't give it that much of thoughts. Any ideas about the approach that I should take in order to achieve what i'm looking for?.
-(none related things)I may also add that jsf implements csrf protection that made me think about maybe sessionscoped could mean something that it's not

Comment: There are many ways to attack a web application, and many ways to protect it. The most important thing is to secure your business layer, i.e. your EJB services. I'd start with an simple check for authenticated users and their roles in each business method. Imo Spring Security would be overkill for your ordinary use case. If your apps grows more complex, you probably need to refactor anyway.

Comment: OffTopic: If you are using EJB's I would certainly not go the Spring way... Shiro, PicketLink etc is more suitable then

Comment: @shreyanshjogi - what you say is not true. Every Java EE vendor there is provides mechanisms for authentication and authorisation without the need for developer defined filters and/or interceptors.

Comment: @yoreliviwesky - you have not said whether or not you have set up any kind of authentication in your web tier, such as user login, and if so, how it was done.